# error_type":"OAuthAccessTokenException","code":400,.. (instagram)

Tags: angularjs, instagram-api

I am accessing the instagram API to display content from a specific account, however I get this error:

```
/**/ JSON_CALLBACK({"meta":{"error_type":"OAuthAccessTokenException","code":400,"error_message":"The access_token provided is invalid."}})
```

I have registered my app in https://www.instagram.com/developer/

bit when accessing here for example I get that above error:

```
   var endpoint = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/" + user_id + "/media/recent/?";
    endpoint += "?count=99";
    endpoint += "&client_id=" + client_id;
    endpoint += "&callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
```

Comment: Can you please help me here ? https://stackoverflow.com/q/60929536/6839690

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot access this API with `client_id` anymore, you have to authenticate, get an `access_token` and make API call with `access_token`, see documentation for this endpoint here:
https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_media_recent

Comment: Can you please help me here? https://stackoverflow.com/q/60929536/6839690