# Instagram recent liked API not returning latest data

Tags: api, instagram

We want to make use of Instagram API using :

https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent?access_token=xxxx

It's working, and returning several liked data for particular user, but not the recent one. Even if the user doing some likes, they're not returned via API call.

Is anyone experiencing the same problem?
fyi that we already pass the submission steps, public_content scope is approved, and permission for this scope is also requested for the user, so i don't think that this is "sandbox" problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35066490/error-typeoauthaccesstokenexception-code400-instagram

Comment: I have the same problem