# Instagram : access_token is invalid

Tags: instagram, instagram-graph-api

I want to retrieve images of Instagram account. For that, I create app and generate access token and when I use that access_token. It's return error

Error :

> /**/ jQuery1124087702457304885_1585566511276({"meta": {"code": 400, "error_type": "OAuthAccessTokenException", "error_message": "The access_token provided is invalid."}})

URL :

> https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/852059411961788/media/recent/?access_token=EAAHWnFQtxLEBAEQOqxA0dhHKVHjZAUkQWaqplUAjK23b3jDaH0kpxhmb1TBlc5lSfZCXwuZBoRR0XbR0fFaeY3MX2W8EyBHvANXTH4Q90OZBpwMBbyVuFGD1TMKZA9a86ahFhg3rcXnXh06uySPKudCBwZCKgCB7uMIOFhzvihM2DoAafrc4aabSZA5CLaMXjpYnZAc9BYU6ZBDvN3WldPbZBVA0qUIG0hwZAVqjzhbFwXKy3VtLfSdjLQQ&callback=jQuery1124087702457304885_1585566511276&_=1585566511277

What am I missing or where I do mistake?

Can anyone please help me.

I follow this steps : https://developers.facebook.com/tools/

Answer (score 0):

Exactly the same thing is happning to me, i've tried everything and i can't still find a way for the API to work.